# Can event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId be spoofed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, acl, spoofing

I'm trying to do ACL by asserting if the item in DynamoDB whose field UserId is really the one logged in which is `event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId`.

But, I'm afraid that it can be spoofed just like HTTP headers etc.

My question is, is that safe?

Answer (score 2):

No, this cannot be spoofed in the same way HTTP request headers can.  If the request comes in through API Gateway, as a Lambda proxy integration, then there's nothing the browser can do that would allow these values to be overwritten, because this portion of the Lambda event structure is created by API Gateway and not copied from the request.  Anything injected into the HTTP request would appear elsewhere in the event structure -- not here.  (The HTTP request is in `event.input` -- which is a sibling object of `event.requestContext` -- not a parent.)

But then again... yes, this could be spoofed in certain other misconfiguration scenarios -- if, for example, your Lambda function allows itself to be invoked other than by your API Gateway deployment -- then of course the invoker could craft an entire `event` structure that had nothing to do with any HTTP request and invoke your Lambda function with it.  This is perhaps too obvious to mention, since it's implicit from the way you can test a Lambda function from the console, but I mention it for thoroughness.  Send a forged test event to your Lambda function using the Lambda console's test function, and naturally the Lambda function processes what you sent it.

So, unsurprisingly, with careless and overly broad permissions, yes, anything is possible... but used as intended behind API Gateway, as a Lambda Proxy Integration, I'd say no.

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching this question for many hours.

I found this [post](https://tech.mybuilder.com/mince-pie-challenge-authentication-with-amazon-cognito-and-json-web-tokens/) where the author extracts the `userId` from the Token via:

```
const userId = await services.getUserIdFromToken(event.headers.Authorization);
```

This appears to be a safer way to handle setting the userId but all the other examples I have seen use `event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId`.